# Grouping rows which has same value in same column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having a hard to achieve this grouping issue. I have a master table that contains names in `name` column. And there is another table connected to master table by **belongsTo** relationship and contains plans for each names.

The problem is, in master table some names repeating a couple of times. The structure is like below.

```
|       name        | 
--------------------
|       Mark
|       Mark 
|       Jack
|       Alistair
|       Oliver
|       Jack
```

I want to group rows if has same value(name). At the same time try to avoid to lose connected tables data. Because each names has own plan in another table.

```
Master::select('name')
        ->groupBy('name')
        ->get();
```

If I do something like above I am grouping names. But this time of course I am losing the connected table's data.

Is there anyway to achieve, what I wanted here.

Here is the table structure and Models for the connection between tables.

**master table**

```
    Schema::create('masters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**plan table**

```
   Schema::create('plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('master_id');
        $table->string('website');
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('plan_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**master model**

```
public $with = ["plan];

public function plan()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Plan");
}
```

**plan model**

```
public function master()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Master");
}
```

Comment: are you using the name to connect two tables is there any primary key or not plz provide the full table structure.

Comment: I updated the question. And provide the tables structure with the models. @CHARITRASHRESTHA please take look at.

Comment: you can not use the name for connecting two tables as they don't have unique values. explain why are you grouping the name. Are both Mark the same person? if yes then just link the table by primary key. No need to use group by

Comment: yes they are. But each Mark holds different plan, in plan table. what I am trying to do here. group the Marks, and also group the plans... @CHARITRASHRESTHA

Comment: as your question if each name has a different plan why would you like to merge that.  if you want to achieve that at any cost you can have one more column in the master table, as name1 plan etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Group by doesnot allows us to select all the column so you can join and use order by.

```
DB::table('masters as m')->select(m.*,p.*)
->join('plans as p', 'p.master_id', '=','m.id')
->orderBy('m.name', 'asc')
->orderBy('p.id', 'asc')
```

Comment: thank you,  but something wrong with the query. Because it just returning names... and names are repeating same count of plans